# Download generated XML with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps script bound to a Spreadsheet that convert the spreadsheet to XML.

Is there a way to download the generated XML file onto the user computer when the task is finished ?

I want it to behave just like the "file > Download to format" function of Spreadsheet.

Thanks

Comment: Aren't you actually asking to *upload* (push) the file to another computer? Would you please clarify. If this is the case (push to another computer): not without an HTTPS endpoint to push the file to.  Otherwise, if it's a download from the destination computer (pull), you'll need a timed process on the destination device. At least that's how i have cracked this nut in the past.

Comment: No, I just want to download (pull) the generated XML file onto the current computer which is running the spreadsheet and whom made the action of "exporting to xml"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this sample script? Please think of this as one of several answers.

In order to use this sample, at first, please set file ID of your generated XML file. For this, for example, it is considered the following methods.

1. When users click a download button, it creates XML file and retrieves the file ID.
2. Save the file ID of XML file using PropertiesService when the XML file is created, and when users click a download button, it retrieves the file ID.

### FLow :

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. By opening spreadsheet, create a menu for downloading at menu bar.

   - Also you can directly run `onOpen()`.
2. When users click a download button, retrieve file ID at GAS side.
3. Create download URL from the file ID. Download URL and filename are sent to `download(obj)` of Javascript.
4. Create a tag for downloading and click it at Javascript side.

   - By this, users can download the file of file ID.

### Sample scripts :

#### Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
                .createMenu('download')
                .addItem('download files', 'dialog')
                .addToUi();
}

function dialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('download');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Sample dialog');
}

function getDownloadUrl() {
  var id = "### file id ###"; // Please put file ID of your generated XLM file.

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  return {
    url: file.getDownloadUrl().replace("?e=download&gd=true",""),
    filename: file.getName()
  };
}
```

#### download.html

```
<input type="button" value="download" onclick="getUrl()" />
<script>
  function getUrl() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(download).getDownloadUrl();
  }

  function download(obj) {
    var d = document.createElement('a');
    d.href = obj.url;
    d.download = obj.filename;
    d.click();
  }
</script>
```

#### Note :

This sample script is very simple. So please modify this for your environment.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: It works almost great, I generated the file in Drive and then the browser tries to download automatically the file. However, the download fails with "Autorization Required" even though I specified `file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW)` and I can read the file in the drive app. Do you know what's wrong with the authorization ?

Comment: Never mind, it works. In the downloadUrl, the `e=download&gd=true` was not at the beginning so I removed `?` from the replace pattern and I work perfectly. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @pdegand59 I'm happy that I can help you. Thank you, too.